# How I can delete in VIM all text from current line to end of file?

Tags: file, vim, text

I have very large files (more than 10Gb). I need only some lines from the top of the file. Is it possible (in vim) to delete the rest of the file (from current line to the end of file)?

Comment: I know you want to use Vim, but I'd do a shell command like:

`head -n <number_of_lines> <filename> > <truncated_filename>`

Where `-n` is the parameter for the number of lines you want from the top

Answer (score 448, accepted):

<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> will delete from the current line to the end of file

<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> will delete from the cursor to the end of the file

But if this file is as large as you say, you may be better off reading the first few lines with `head` rather than editing and saving the file.

```
head hugefile > firstlines
```

(If you are on Windows you can use the Win32 port of `head`)

Comment: you can specify how many lines `head` supplies with eg: `head -n20 hugefile` for the first 20 lines. n defaults to 10.

Comment: Need a motivation for `head`? Using dG on a large file (1G+) takes a lot of time (e.g., 5 minutes).

Comment: For those looking for the converse, `dgg` will delete from the current line to the start of the file.

Comment: d Ctrl+End did not work for me.  d Shift+End did though to delete from the cursor to the end of the line.

Comment: Thx! BTW, there is a keyboard substitute for <END> keystroke?

Answer (score 91):

Go to the first line from which you would like to delete, and press the keys <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>

Comment: don't press ":" before you type dG

Answer (score 44):

<kbd>:</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>,</kbd><kbd>$</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>

This will delete all content from current line to end of the file. This is very useful when you're dealing with test vector generation or stripping.

Comment: I prefer to have more control of the starting line, so I use: `:<line number>,$d` for example: `:3,$d` will delete from line 3 to the end of file

Answer (score 6):

I use the following steps to do the same-

1. Make sure you are in the normal mode by pressing **`Esc`** .
2. Enter the Visual mode by pressing **`V`** .
3. Press **`G`** i.e **`Shift + g`** to select the text from the cursor to the end of the file .
4. Now press **`x`** to delete the selected text .

Answer (score 1):

Just add another way , in normal mode , type `ctrl+v` then `G`, select the rest, then `D`, I don't think it is effective , you should do like @Ed Guiness, head -n 20 > filename in linux.